# Provide additional provider in MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

Imagine you have Angular service without provideIn, so it is available only in certain components and their children. Now one such component opens MatDialog -- is it possible to have that service injected there?

As I see by default Angular does not count MatDialog component as a child of caller component and also I do not see any settings to change that.

P.S. Service here is stateful, so just putting it to providers of MyDialogComponent will create new service, which is not desired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is provide the dialog.open method with ViewContainerRef where the desired service instance lives. 'VERY_IMPORTANT_SERVICE' will be available for injection in 'SomeComponent'. See the code below

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    providers: [ VERY_IMPORTANT_SERVICE ]
})
export class Component {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

    openDialog() {
       this.dialog.open(SomeComponent, {
           viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO dialog service should include host component injector by itself

Comment: What if my service is provided in a grandfather component? Should passing ViewContainerRef from the parent component still work? It's apparently not working for me. Hence asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide your service into the root, then you have to provide it either in

- An Angular feature (component, directive ...)
- An Angular module

Providing it into a feature implies that everytime that feature gets created, it gets an instance of that service.

If you provide it in the module, it implies that everytime the module is created, one instance of that service is created, which will be common for every feature in that module.

If you wish to provide the module instance to your dialog component, you can. If you choose the feature providing, then you will have a new instance of that service into your dialog component (which will be useless to keep a state from your "parent" component).

I hope it answers the question, and if not, feel free to ask for more explanation.

Comment: Can you show how can I provide the module instance to dialog component. I understand that I can put it as property to dialog data, but I would choose another option if there is one.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov simply add the provider to the `providers: [...]` metadata of your module. It then becomes available for the whole module (including the `entryComponents` that you have declared)